# Start task failed in Azure batch when trying to install python

Tags: azure, azure-data-factory, azure-batch

I have a batch pool with two nodes. The start task is as follows:

```
/bin/bash -c "sudo apt-get update -y
sudo apt-get install -y python3-azure"
```

I am trying to install python on my nodes so that I can run a python script using batch in Azure Data Factory. When trying this I get the Error "start task failed"
My question is, do I even need to install python somehow? If yes, how can a change my start task to make it work?

Here is the error message from the startup/stderr.txt:
"sudo: a terminal is required to read the password; either use the -S option to read from standard input or configure an askpass helper
sudo: a terminal is required to read the password; either use the -S option to read from standard input or configure an askpass helper"

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The solution to this problem is: Remove both "sudo" from the code and change the user that is used to execute the startup command to admin.